# Mule Standalone ESB Community version not regognizing any ftp:endpoint

Tags: ftp, mule, mule-studio

I've created a simple mule flow with Mule Studio:

```
<flow name="soapService" doc:name="soapService">
        <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8888"
            exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
            <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.testing.Person" />
        </http:inbound-endpoint>

        <component class="com.testing.TestComponent" doc:name="Java"/>
        <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="21" outputPattern="#[function:datestamp:dd-MM-yy]_#[function:systime]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FTP"  password="xxx"  user="ftpuser"/>
        <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="xxx" user="xxx" password="xxx" to="xxx@xxx.com" from="xxx@xxx.com" subject="Testing" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP"/>

</flow>
```

This works fine on mule Studio launch, Run as -> Mule application, but when i export it as mule deployable archive and start my mule standalone esb, it fails to deploy, with nested exception `Invalid content was found starting with element 'ftp:inbound-endpoint'.`

If I remove the ftp:endpoint, it works fine. Same in other flows too. any ftp-endpoint, in or outbound causes an exception.

Mulestudio version: 3.4.0

mule-standalone-3.4.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use the Community Runtime you have to install it manually.
http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Adding+Community+Runtime

After this you can use CE namespaces without any problems.

HTH

Comment: Yes, noticed this later, when tried to find out, why the studio was changing path.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was, that Mule Studio enters the enterprise edition namespace and url for the ftp endpoint.

See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/FTP+Transport+Reference

Even tough you change the namespace and url in the Mule Studio, it changes it back to the ee one. So I had to export the project and open the flow-file and make the changes before deploying the zip.

```
    <mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ce/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd">
```

to

```
<mule xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/3.4/mule-ftp.xsd">
```

Comment: I have the same issue. Isn't this a bug that should be taken care of in Mule Studio?